Android app using Chaquopy to run Qwen2-0.5B-Instruct model
I'm developing an Android app using Chaquopy to run the Qwen2-0.5B-Instruct model. I'm facing persistent dependency issues, particularly with transformers and tokenizers.
Current setup:
Android app with Chaquopy
Python 3.8
Trying to use Qwen2-0.5B-Instruct model
Gradle configuration:
gradleCopypython {
    version "3.8"
    pip {
        install "torch==1.8.1"
        install "numpy"
        install "transformers==4.41.2"
        install "safetensors==0.3.1"
        install "tokenizers==0.10.3"
    }
}

Python code:
pythonCopyfrom transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForCausalLM

checkpoint = "model_files/Qwen2-0.5B-Instruct"

def initialize_model():
    global tokenizer, model
    tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(checkpoint)
    model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(checkpoint)

def interpret_text(text):
    if tokenizer is None or model is None:
        initialize_model()
    inputs = tokenizer.encode(text, return_tensors="pt")
    outputs = model.generate(inputs, max_length=50)
    return tokenizer.decode(outputs[0], skip_special_tokens=True)

Issues:
Dependency conflicts between transformers, tokenizers, and packaging
Latest error: InvalidVersion: Invalid version: '0.10.1,<0.11'
Attempted solutions:
Tried various versions of transformers and tokenizers
Attempted to use pre-built wheels and build from source
Experimented with different Python package combinations
ONNX isn't an option as it doesn't support Qwen models currently.
I'm looking for suggestions on how to resolve these dependency issues or alternative approaches to run this model in an Android environment. Any insights or workarounds would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance!
